# Full rank decomposition, where matrix come from?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

While studying full rank decomposition, I found the following:

[image]

I understand it until $C$. Where does $C$ comes from?

Comment: $C$ is just the first two (non-zero) lines of $A$.

Comment: Ok. May I also ask why $B$ is made by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$? And why $C$ is just the first two (non-zero) lines of $A$?

Comment: $B$ is made up of the columns of $A$ that have pivot elements in the reduced form of $A$. In other words, the earliest columns you can pick if you want to pick a maximal set of linearly independent columns of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows of matrix $C$ are just a basis for rows of matrix $A$.

The rows of matrix $B$ are the combination coefficient such that $BC=A$.

Indeed the left multiplication $BC$ correspond to a row combination of the rows of $C$.

Comment: So, the idea is to make $B$ selecting any $\alpha_i$ and then make $C$ so that $A=BC$. Any other hints on how to make $B$ and $C$?

Comment: The idea is to find C  selecting the two row basis vector for the row space of $A$, that's the first part. Then you need to find B such that $BC=A$. You can construct $B$ by matrix operation or solving the corresponding systems to find $\alpha_i$. In thi case it's easy find B simply by inspection.